# How to connect to a windows docker container's exposed ports from a hyper-v VM?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, portforwarding

When I run the command to run a windows docker container and expose the ports to the host, I can ping the container and connect to it. The problem is I now want to do this from a Hyper-V VM that's connected to the host ethernet network through a virtual switch.

There's no options for bridged adapter in Hyper-V, only in Virtualbox. Windows docker container network drivers are also NAT by default, as opposed to bridge in Linux containers.

I've tried Overlay network drivers to connect to Docker Swarm but that is also not supported in Windows containers. I've also tried adding static routes to the Windows routing table using specified network destination, subnet masks, and gateways, but no luck there too.

The only option I haven't tried is port mapping/forwarding, but I'm not much of a networking guy and the documentation I could find online for Hyper-V port mapping involves NAT configuration with virtual switches. I'm not sure what to try next.

```
docker run --rm --name rabbitmqtest -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --ip 192.168.130.4
5 -t imgtest containerNetwork
```

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Hyper-V creates a Default Switch, connected to the Default Network, that is used by guest VMs to connect to the host network via NAT.

You can get the network details from the guest VM via the `ipconfig` command. For example, a current machine I have:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.131.236
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.131.225
```

The default gateway is basically the host machine, so you should be able to access the mapped ports directly on that IP address.

For example, on my machine I am also running Elastic Stack in a container, with the Kibana port mapped to 32771.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                NAMES
9fa6fe19a911        sebp/elk:latest     "/usr/local/bin/star…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:32772->5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32771->5601/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->9300/tcp   elk
```

To access Kibana from the guest VM, I simply browse to `http://192.168.131.225:32771/`

In your case, you should be able to access the RabbitMQ web UI, of the docker container, from the Hyper-V guest VM, at `http://192.168.<your gateway>:15672/`

**Edit:** You might also need to remove the specific IP address binding, so that the ports are mapped on all interfaces, including the Hyper-V Default Network.

**Note:** Hyper-V also supports Internal and Shared (bridged) networks, which could also be used in a similar fashion. Earlier versions of Hyper-V did not have the default NAT (but you could use Windows Internet Connection Sharing to create NAT).